# SQLAlchemy not finding Postgres table connected with postgres_fdw

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgres-fdw

Please excuse any terminology typos, don't have a lot of experience with databases other than SQLite.  I'm trying to replicate what I would do in SQLite where I could ATTACH a database to a second database and query across all the tables.  I wasn't using SQLAlchemy with SQLite

I'm working with SQLAlchemy 1.0.13, Postgres 9.5 and Python 3.5.2 (using Anaconda) on Win7/54.  I have connected two databases (on localhost) using postgres_fdw and imported a few of the tables from the secondary database.  I can successfully manually query the connected table with SQL in PgAdminIII and from Python using psycopg2.  With SQLAlchemy I've tried:

```
# Same connection string info that psycopg2 used
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)

class TestTable(Base):
    __table__ = Table('test_table', Base.metadata,
                      autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

    # Added this when I got the error the first time
    # test_id is a primary key in the secondary table
    Column('test_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
```

and get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|TestTable|test_table could not
assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'test_table'
```

Then I tried:

```
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
print(insp.get_table_names())
```

and the attached tables aren't listed (the tables from the primary database do show up).  Is there a way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to map a table [SQLAlchemy needs there to be at least one column denoted as a primary key column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key). This does not mean that the column need actually be a primary key column in the eyes of the database, though it is a good idea. Depending on how you've imported the table from your foreign schema it may not have a representation of a primary key constraint, or any other constraints for that matter. You can work around this by either [overriding the reflected primary key column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#overriding-reflected-columns) in the **`Table` instance** (not in the mapped classes body), or better yet tell the mapper what columns comprise the candidate key:

```
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)

test_table = Table('test_table', Base.metadata,
                   autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

class TestTable(Base):
    __table__ = test_table
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key': (test_table.c.test_id, )  # candidate key columns
    }
```

To inspect foreign table names use the [`PGInspector.get_foreign_table_names()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.PGInspector.get_foreign_table_names) method:

```
print(insp.get_foreign_table_names())
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on sibling answer by @ilja.

When using the SQLAlchemy [automap](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html#basic-use) feature to automatically generate mapped classes and relationships from an existing database schema, I found that the `__mapper_args__` solution didn't create the model.

This alternative method where you [manually define the private key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#overriding-reflected-columns) will correctly enable `automap` to create your model.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine, Text
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.schema import Table

Base = automap_base()

engine = create_engine(conn_str, convert_unicode=True)

pk = Column('uid', Text, primary_key=True)
test_table = Table(
    'test_table', Base.metadata, pk, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine
)

# Inspect postgres schema
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

print(dict(Base.classes))
print(test_table)
```